# Single-user binary installation location?

Tags: users, non-root-user, home, binary

I'd like to install a binary for only my user, because I don't have root, and therefore don't have access to `/usr/bin`. I've tried `~/bin`, and it can't find the binary. I'm on Mac OS 10.6.7. Is there any other binary folder that can usually be user-modified, or any way to get it to recognize `~/bin`?

My `.profile`:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user's BASH environment variables can be defined in `~/.profile`. Add a line to this file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

To read the new PATH variable now:

```
. ~/.profile
```

or

```
source ~/.profile
```

(The `.` and `source` are synonyms.)

Then to see that the PATH variable was updated:

```
echo $PATH
```

**Update**

I have never seen `{}` in a PATH environment variable?

```
PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:~/bin"
export $PATH
```

Or create a text file containing a path in /etc/paths.d/ so all shells and users get the path...

```
echo "~/bin/" > /etc/paths.d/home
```

Comment: So you can add `~/bin` (or preferably `~/.bin`) to the list of places that it looks for binaries in?

Comment: @tkbx that is what he is doin here. I don't think `~/.bin` is preferable, as `~/bin` is fairly standard and even configured by default in some operating systems.

Comment: @Christopher I've edited my answer to show my .profile. How can I modify this to add ~/bin without breaking whatever is already there?